# AIR: url navigation via <a> link in htmlText

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, air, htmltext

I have AIR application and `mx:Label` with `htmlText` property (`<a href='http://www.adobe.com'>Navigate to Adobe.com.</a>)`. For some reason nothing happens when I click it. It works in not-AIR application, but does not in AIR one. Any suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that you have the *selectable* property set to *true* or otherwise it won't work.

```
<mx:Label selectable="true">
    <mx:htmlText>
        <![CDATA[ <a href='http://www.adobe.com'>Navigate to Adobe.com.</a> ]]>
    </mx:htmlText>
</mx:Label>
```